# How to pass arguments to an LDAP custom socket factory with JNDI?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I'm using JNDI to make LDAP connections. Example:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, LDAPS_URL);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "EXTERNAL");
env.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "ldaptest.CustomSocketFactory");
...
```

I need to pass parameters at run time to the CustomSocketFactory. Specifically a reference to a client certificate.

How can I do this?
I could use thread local storage.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I am having the very same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you may be looking for something like this:

```
env.put("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keystorePath);
//Where keystorePath is the path to the Keys file resource

env.put("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
```

Comment: This approach only allows one cert to be used at run time. I'm managing my own key store (with key managers and trust managers) and  I need to manage and supply more than one cert to different ldap servers.

Comment: ok, that was all my knowledge on that, sorry couldnt help, i will keep an eye on this question.

Answer (score 3):

Actually thread local is only way to solve this I found so far.
I posted my solution here:

[jndi LDAPS custom HostnameVerifier and TrustManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394864/jndi-ldaps-custom-hostnameverifier-and-trustmanager)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, all you can do is pass a class name (see icrovett's answer) and JNDI will call the getDefault() method via reflection. So you can't really pass any arguments there. So I think there is no nice and clean solution.

For my needs, I've built a `SelectiveLdapSslSocketFactory`, which contains a static Map mapping hosts to different SSLSocketFactories. First, you can register your custom `SSLSocketFactories` for different hosts. Then, when any of the `createSocket(...)` methods is called, it knows the host the socket is created for so the call can be delegated to the corresponding `SSLSocketFactory`. It also contains a `defaultSslSocketFactory` used for hosts without any mapping and also in the `getDefaultCipherSuites()` and `getSupportedCipherSuites()` methods. I'm not sure, if it's completely correct but it works fine for me so test it if you like:

```
public class SelectiveLdapSslSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private static SSLSocketFactory defaultSslSocketFactory;
    private static final Map<String, SSLSocketFactory> hostToSslSocketFactoryMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    {
        try {
            defaultSslSocketFactory = <yourOwnDefaultSslSocketFactory>;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.warn(ex, "Couldn't initialize a defaultSslSocketFactory for LDAP connections!");
        }
    }

    public static SSLSocketFactory getRegisteredSslSocketFactory(String host) {
        return hostToSslSocketFactoryMap.get(host);
    }

    public static void registerSslSocketFactory(String host, SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) {
        hostToSslSocketFactoryMap.put(host, sslSocketFactory);
    }

    public static void deregisterSslSocketFactory(String host) {
        hostToSslSocketFactoryMap.remove(host);
    }

    public SelectiveLdapSslSocketFactory() {
    }

    public static SocketFactory getDefault() {
        return new SelectiveLdapSslSocketFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return defaultSslSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return defaultSslSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = Objects.requireNonNullElse(hostToSslSocketFactoryMap.get(host), defaultSslSocketFactory);
        return sslSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = Objects.requireNonNullElse(hostToSslSocketFactoryMap.get(host), defaultSslSocketFactory);
        return sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = Objects.requireNonNullElse(hostToSslSocketFactoryMap.get(host), defaultSslSocketFactory);
        return sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getSslSocketFactory(host);
        return sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getSslSocketFactory(address);
        return sslSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort);
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory getSslSocketFactory(InetAddress inetAddress) {
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = hostToSslSocketFactoryMap.get(Objects.requireNonNullElse(inetAddress.getCanonicalHostName(), ""));
        if (sslSocketFactory == null) {
            sslSocketFactory = hostToSslSocketFactoryMap.get(Objects.requireNonNullElse(inetAddress.getHostName(), ""));
            if (sslSocketFactory == null) {
                sslSocketFactory = hostToSslSocketFactoryMap.get(Objects.requireNonNullElse(inetAddress.getHostAddress(), ""));
                if (sslSocketFactory == null) {
                    sslSocketFactory = defaultSslSocketFactory;
                }
            }
        }
        return sslSocketFactory;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like:

```
...
SelectiveLdapSslSocketFactory.registerSslSocketFactory(host01, sslSocketFactory01);
SelectiveLdapSslSocketFactory.registerSslSocketFactory(host02, sslSocketFactory02);
SelectiveLdapSslSocketFactory.registerSslSocketFactory(host03, sslSocketFactory03);

props.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", SelectiveLdapSslSocketFactory.class.getName());
```